# Simple authorization check causes redux store Provider to crash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an application built in React and Redux that's been working fine until I implemented a simple `localStorage` check to render either the `App` or an auth page I've called `Gateway`:

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./redux/store";

import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";

import Settings from "./views/Settings";
import Gateway from "./views/Gateway";
import Profile from "./views/Profile";
import Signup from "./views/Signup";
import NewTestimonialPage from "./views/NewTestimonialPage";
import NotFoundPage from "./views/NotFoundPage";

import "./styles/App.scss";

function App() {
  // new additions start here...
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === "true"
  );

  if (!loggedIn) {
    return <Gateway />;
  }
...and end here
  
  return (
    <Router>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavBar />
        <div className="navbar-dodger"></div>
        <div className="App">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Gateway} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
            <Route path="/settings/:userId" component={Settings} />
            <Route path="/profile/:userId" component={Profile} />
            <Route
              path="/new-testimonial/:userId"
              component={NewTestimonialPage}
            />
            <Route path="/404" component={NotFoundPage} />
            <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Provider>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Without the code between comments, everything was 100% fine.

Now, I throw this error:

`Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(EmailCheck)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(EmailCheck) in connect options.`

If I render the provider inside that if-block as well, it works. Why? Why do I need a store if I'm not using redux in any way inside `Gateway`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using redux inside `<Gateway>` component then your component must be wrapped in `<Provider>`

It should look like :

```
return (
  <Router>
    <Provider store={store}>
      {!loggedIn ?? <Gateway /> : <YourApplication />}
    </Provider>
  </Router>
);
```

Create a component for the app like
YourApplication.js:

```
return (
  <>    
    <NavBar />
    <div className="navbar-dodger"></div>
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Gateway} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route path="/settings/:userId" component={Settings} />
        <Route path="/profile/:userId" component={Profile} />
        <Route
          path="/new-testimonial/:userId"
          component={NewTestimonialPage}
        />
        <Route path="/404" component={NotFoundPage} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  <>
);
```